# ERROR: Nginx is not configured as a service

Tags: nginx, loggly

when configuring the loggly agent for nginx it returns. ERROR: Nginx is not configured as a service. Is there something missing in a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Loggly's nginx install script](https://www.loggly.com/install/configure-nginx.sh) I saw, that it's just checking SysV init.
Obviously you've setup a new Box, using Systemd instead of SysV init. The Loggly installer fails with Systemd; they have to update their scripts.

You'll have to [configure all the stuff manually](https://www.loggly.com/docs/nginx-server-logs/) for the time being.